# How to change the variable name in the request path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, path

I'd like to change the name of a variable when I pass it through a request, for example:

I have this link_to

```
<%= link_to 'Checkout', article_path(price: price.id) %>
```

And this respond me with the next path:

```
http://localhost:3000/article?price=price_1Kdamcakraj
```

I wish "price_1Kdamcakraj" was hidden or could be disguised under another name

Comment: Take a look at this -  https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: Another option - make it a post request

Comment: No matter if you use GET or POST a user can still just alter the parameter. This smells of security by obscurity.